# EhCache's CacheStatistics getCacheHits vs getInMemoryHits

Tags: java, caching, memory, ehcache

As specified in [CacheStatistics](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/management/CacheStatistics.html):

- getCacheHits():
  The number of times a requested item was found in the cache.
- getInMemoryHits(): 
  Number of times a requested item was found in the Memory Store.

What actually is this memory store?  I had been thinking that "a cache" is a "in memory" instance in JVM as well?
What is the difference between cache and memory store in ehcache?  In what scenarios will the values returned be different?

Answer (score 2):

EhCache can indeed store items on disk.  It's not in memory only.

http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart#temporary-disk-storage

If you'd like it to be, you can set this setting and then the results of hits and in-memory hits will be the same.

```
<cache>
  <persistence strategy="none"/>
</cache>
```

Comment: are you saying CacheStatistics.getCacheHits() = getInMemoryHits() +  getOnDiskHits() ?